# Java и JSON проблема с парсингом

Tags: java, android, json

Есть объект, не получается достать от туда gameId, с помощью JSONObject и JSONArray, заранее спасибо за помощь!

```
{
"matches": [
    {
        "lane": "JUNGLE",
        "gameId": 3468011952,
        "champion": 19,
        "platformId": "EUW1",
        "timestamp": 1514054758338,
        "queue": 430,
        "role": "NONE",
        "season": 9
    },
}

 JSONObject array = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                JSONArray matches_array = array.getJSONArray("matches");
                JSONObject obj = matches_array.getJSONObject(0);
```

Comment: Не по теме, но попробуйте Jackson вместо Jsonobject

Comment: Он умеет json2pojo

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так

```
JSONObject array = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
JSONArray matches_array = array.getJSONArray("matches");
JSONObject obj = matches_array.getJSONObject(0);

Log.i("log__", "obj - " + obj.getString("gameId"));
```

На выходе

```
I/log__: obj - 3468011952
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, уже всё было правильно, просто в api есть ошибка, поле не int , а string